# Wait until task completed before running it again

Tags: swift, task, wait, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to animate the background of my view for several times. For example(of course it's need to be dynamic solution) for 4 seconds, each second it will animate from white to black. what we expect:
second:

1. white to black to white
2. white to black to white
3. white to black to white
4. white to black to white

I tried using for and even delay(dispatch delay),and it will run it only 1 time 
and than stop. This is what I tried.

```
for var index = 0; index < 3; ++index {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.33333, delay: 0.333333, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
        println(elapsedTime)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }) { (completed : (Bool)) -> Void in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.333333, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        })
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can run these commands, wait until they complete and than run them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that `for` loop, you're essentially setting up all four animations to run at the same time. If you make that animation code a function, you can call it recursively from the completion block for your white animation:

```
func animateBackground(times: Int) {
    if times == 0 { return }

    let blackAnimation = { self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor() }
    let whiteAnimation = { self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor() }
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.33333, delay: 0.333333, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: blackAnimation) {
        completedBlack in // completion block 1

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.333333, animations: whiteAnimation) {
            completedWhite in // completion block 2
            self.animateBackground(times - 1)
        }
    }
}
```

And the initial call looks like:

```
animateBackground(4)
```

Comment: no idea why it crushes, Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT , i think i havent implement it good , i just copy pasted the function and called it in a button action like you did, any reason why it crushed?

Comment: @roimulia that may be because you're you're calling UIView methods in the callback of the previous animation, I'm new to this but... I think if the animations run on a background thread, that may cause problems. Try wrapping the code in a dispatch to the main queue

Comment: Thanks Diogo! long time since i posted this answer , figure it already while ago - NEVER change UI on background theards , only main :)